# Swift Firebase long loading time for user data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app has about 500 users. In one screen I am loading the student users for teachers to select.  The list of students(400) is taking over 20 seconds to populate.  I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to populate the data. The data to populate is uid, first, last, email.

Here is my function to fetch the student users.

```
  var filteredUsers = [User]()
var users = [User]()

fileprivate func fetchFollowingUserIds() {

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("session1AllStudents")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let userIdsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        print(userIdsDictionary)

        userIdsDictionary.forEach({ (key, value) in
            HUD.show(.labeledProgress(title: "Finding Students", subtitle: nil))
            Database.fetchStudentUsersWithUID(uid: key, completion: { (user) in

                self.users.append(user)
                print(self.users)
                self.users.sort(by: { (u1, u2) -> Bool in

                    return u1.lastName.compare(u2.lastName) == .orderedAscending
                })

                self.filteredUsers = self.users
                print(self.filteredUsers.count)
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                HUD.hide()
            })

        })


    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch following userids:", err)
    }

}

extension Database {
static func fetchStudentUsersWithUID(uid: String, completion: @escaping (User) -> ()) {

    Database.database().reference().child("studentUsers").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let userDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        let user = User(uid: uid, dictionary: userDictionary)
        completion(user)

    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch user for posts:", err)
    }
}
```

}

The database "session1AllStudents" is a list of all students still let to select and has the UID:true key:value pair.

Then I am getting the student info from "studentUsers" from the UID in the list.

--UPDATED--

I used the following after a looking at the comments.

```
func fetchRemainingStudents() {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("session1AllStudents").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        HUD.show(.labeledProgress(title: "Finding Students", subtitle: nil))
        for snap in snapshot.children {
            let studentsSnap = snap as! DataSnapshot
            let studentsKey = studentsSnap.key
            let studentDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

            var aStudent = User(uid: studentsKey, dictionary: studentDict)
            let userRef = ref.child("studentUsers").child(studentsKey)
            userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
                let firstName = userDict["firstName"] as! String
                let lastName = userDict["lastName"] as! String
                let email = userDict["email"] as! String

                aStudent.firstName = firstName
                aStudent.lastName = lastName
                aStudent.email = email
                self.users.append(aStudent)

                self.filteredUsers = self.users
                print(self.filteredUsers.count)
                self.users.sort(by: { (u1, u2) -> Bool in

                    return u1.lastName.compare(u2.lastName) == .orderedAscending
                })
                HUD.hide()
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            })

        }

    })


}
```

This has helped speed up the data loading.  Maybe down to 1-2 seconds.

Comment: You should be able to load thousands of nodes in less than a second. There are a number of issues with the code in your question which may be part of the problem. You're sorting, reassigning the array and reloading a tableView every time through your loop.

Comment: @Jay Can you help me out with some places that I can make this more efficient?

Comment: Not sure if you reviewed my answer but I updated it slightly for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

You've already updated your code and gotten better peformance but you may be able to revise it further.

I crafted and tested the below code pulling 500 users out of a list of 1000. The total time was .487 seconds.

First we start with a StudentClass and an array to store them in. The array can be used as a dataSource for a tableView for example.

```
class StudentClass {
    var key = ""
    var firstName = ""
    var lastName = ""
    var email = ""

    init(snap: DataSnapshot) {
        let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
        self.key = snap.key
        self.firstName = dict["first_name"] as! String
        self.lastName = dict["last_name"] as! String
        self.email = dict["email"] as! String
    }
}

var studentArray = [StudentClass]()
```

We then have the code to read in the student id's which will populate an array. We then use that array to get the students from Firebase, create the student objects and populate the studentArray

```
func fetchStudents() {

   let studentIdRef = self.ref.child("student_ids")
   let userRef = self.ref.child("users")

   studentIdRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
       var keyArray = [String]()
       for child in snapshot.children {
           let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
           keyArray.append(snap.key)
       }
       let lastElement = keyArray.count - 1

       for (index, key) in keyArray.enumerated() {
           let thisUserRef = userRef.child(key)
           thisUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { userSnap in
               let student = StudentClass(snap: userSnap)
               self.studentArray.append(student)
               if index == lastElement {
                   print("reload tableView")
               }
           })
       }
   })
```

One of the ways to speed things up is to not update the UI until you have all the data read in. We could be using a background thread but in this case, it happens so quickly, it may not be needed.

In the for loop to get each student object, a test is done to see if we have completed reading in all of the student objects and if so, update the ui (tableView.reloadData() for example) when all data has been loaded.